# Google Wallet testing without Merchant Credentials

Tags: android-pay

Has anyone tried using google wallet for testing without having to use or need the credentials that is needed( merchant id, key).

I mean I would like to try first google wallet testing in my web application before having to pay to use google wallet in production, seems it is not in the docs, idk if its possible or not

Answer (score 1):

Signup for a sandbox account or for that matter a production account does not incur any fees. I'm assuming you're asking about Google Wallet Instant Buy. The [sign up link] (https://support.google.com/wallet/business/contact/interest) registers your intent since this is for physical goods and services only and would result in a sandbox account. You can then test your web application to see what the flow looks like.